# Changes in Crypto library?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, hash

I've recently tried to upgrade one of our applications from .Net MVC v2 to v3 and now all login attempts fail. I use Crypto#HashPassword to encrypt the users password and Crypto#VerifyHashedPassword at login to check if the password is valid. But for some reason MVC v3 seems to use an other algorithm than MVC v2. In v2 the generated hashes had always a length of 64 but in MVC v3 the hashes have now a length of 68.

Does anyone know if there has been a change in the Crypto class or if it is possible to configure the used algorithm?

Here is the code:

setting the password

```
public string Password
{
    get { return this._Password; }
    set {  this.CryptedPassword = Crypto.HashPassword(value); }
}
```

verifying the password

```
public bool HasPassword(string password)
{
    return Crypto.VerifyHashedPassword(this.CryptedPassword, password);
}
```

Comment: You might want to post exactly which library you are using (a link would be helpful) and possibly some sample code. I suspect the issue has nothing to do with MVC. Try to isolate the bug as much as possible, possibly in a unit test.

Comment: a hash with a length of 68 sounds odd. Can you check whether the first 64 bytes match and it is putting four bytes of something else on the end?

Comment: @TrueWill The Crypto class comes bundled with the Framework and I'm doing nothing else than calling HashPassword and VerifyHashedPassword. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.crypto%28v=vs.99%29.aspx.

Comment: @Chris No, the first 64 bytes don't match. It's a totaly different hash.

Comment: Strange... `Crypto.HashPassword` is defined as `The password hash is generated with the RFC 2898 algorithm using a 128-bit salt, a 256-bit subkey, and 1000 iterations. The format of the generated hash bytestream is {0x00, salt, subkey}, which is base-64 encoded before it is returned.` You could try to open the two versions with IlSpy and look at how they are done.

Comment: Could this be realted to a machine key issue in the web.config? Without seeing some code this is hard to answer. Usually the machine key is the issue. Make sure it is the same from the web.config in the MVC 2 app.

Comment: What were you using to hash passwords in MVC 2?  The Crypto helper class didn't exist back then; it was introduced with MVC 3 (WebPages v1).  We changed the crypto algorithms between MVC 3 preview and MVC 3 RTM, but this wouldn't affect MVC 2.